# linkerd Inject with helm or namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, linkerd

I can't seem to find a simple answer to my question,

how to use linkerd inject command / options to add when using helm to install a package, e.g. like postgres?

I have done it with another package but that was by adding the annotation command to a values file and supplying that when running the helm install command.

With istio, all I have to do is to add a label on the namespace and it works?

So I started to look into adding the annotation to the namespaces I am working with, using the `kubectl create namespace` command?

However, I cant seem to find a way to add any annotation at the point of creating a namespace, unless I use a file.

So, I either need a way to add this annotation to the namespace with the create command or when installing packages with helm?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there are a couple of ways to do this. It all depends on what you are trying to achieve and how you'd like to manage your underlying infrastructure.

I assume you want to automate the installation of helm charts. If you are going to create the namespace using `kubectl create namespace` then you might be able to follow that up with `kubectl annotate <created-namespace> "linkerd.io/inject=enabled"`.

Alternatively, you can make use of the `Linkerd CLI` and use the inject command provided -- the workflow here would involve a combination of `kubectl` and `linkerd` commands so I'm not sure it's what you're looking for. Nonetheless, you can do something like `kubectl create namespace <my-namespace> -o yaml | linkerd inject - | kubectl apply -f -`.

Last but not least, if you can use `kubectl create namespace` then you might be able to pipe the namespace manifest to kubectl directly and call it a day? You can use something similar to the snippet below:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: foo
  annotations:
    linkerd.io/inject: enabled
EOF
```

Comment: Many thanks - these look like good options - mostly the 1st and 2nd ones, I give them a try and get back to you. And yes I am sort of trying to automate it, but its nothing more than a bash script with some commands.

Comment: The first two options dont seem to work at all. with the 1st option, it just returns an error, ```at lest one annotation update is required```

Comment: Hm, it would be helpful to clarify maybe how you run these commands. For example, with the first approach, I can get it to work without a problem from my shell. `kubectl create namespace foobar; kubectl annotate namespace foobar "linkerd.io/inject=enabled"` -- verifying the namespace with `kubectl get namespace foobar -o yaml | grep "linkerd"` gives me the correct output (linkerd.io/inject: enabled). It would also be helpful to know how the second approach errors.

Comment: Sorry my bad ;( 

i was using ```linkerd.io/inject: enabled``` and not ```linkerd.io/inject=enabled``` and did to know you had to have the ```namespace``` keyword with the annotate command. But I understand, as i am guesting a little here, all sorts of different types can have annotations? and not just namespaces

Comment: but it says it should be disabled in linkerd namespace? https://docs.buoyant.io/runbook/going-to-production/#ensure-the-linkerd-namespace-is-not-eligible-for-auto-injection

Comment: @IvanAracki I think the question was about injecting namespaces in general, not the namespace Linkerd is installed in. You're right that pods in the install namespace shouldn't be injected through a webhook.

Comment: make sense now! 

I was confused why would docs say we just explicitely say it's not eligible for auto-injection, it should be the same as namespace with no annotation at all